# How can I work with mongoose following my design pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question about how to do something on my structure pattern.
I'm using MongoDB as the database, and Mongoose as the ORM.

Basically, I have the following model for Users:

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

export interface IUser {
    _id: string,
    email: string,
    name: string,
    password: string,
    picture: string,
    description: string,
    plans: [
        {
            name: string,
            price: string,
            monthsDuration: number,
        }
    ],
    role: string,
    balance: number,
    createdAt: Date,
}

const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
    email: {
        type: String,
        index: true,
    },
    name: String,
    password: String,
    picture: String,
    description: String,
    plans: [],
    role: String,
    balance: Number,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

const UserModel = model('pvf2_users', UserSchema)
export { UserModel }
```

And then I have the repository that manages the insertion of a new user into the database:

```
import { User } from "@domain/entities/user.entity.js";
import { UserModel } from "@domain/models/user.model.js";
import { UserRepositoryInterface } from "@domain/repositories/user.repository.js";

export class UserDatabaseRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface {

    async insert(user: User): Promise<void> {
        await UserModel.create(user.data)
    }

}
```

The problem is, let's say I want to change from MongoDB to Postgres or whatever other database. Since I'm directly calling the mongoose schema to run the query, I would have to change all repositories that deals with database queries and such. I guess it goes against my design pattern.

How could I build it on a way that I could easily change my database without having to rewrite every file that handles queries? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a mongoose abstract class:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

export abstract class MongooseAbstract {

    public constructor(protected modelName: string) { }

    public async db_insert(data: any): Promise<any> {
        const creation = await mongoose.model(this.modelName).create(data)
        return creation
    }

    public async db_findOne(query: any): Promise<any> {
        const doc = await mongoose.model(this.modelName).findOne(query).lean().exec()
        return doc
    }

    public async db_find(query: any, limit = 15): Promise<any> {
        const docs = await mongoose.model(this.modelName).find(query).limit(limit).lean().exec()
        return docs
    }

    public async db_updateOne(id: string, doc: any): Promise<any> {
        const updatedDoc = await mongoose.model(this.modelName).findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, doc, { new: true }).lean().exec()
        return updatedDoc
    }

}
```